# Reverse Geocoding Libraries

Tags: open-source-gis, openstreetmap, reverse-geocoding

I'm new to GIS and mapping services.

Can anyone tell me what my options are for reverse-geocoding libraries, other than nominatim? I'm most likely going to be working with OpenStreetMap data. So I'll be on the PGSQL/PostGIS stack. Does any of them support the notion of "radius" in their search (which standard Nominatim doesn't support)?

Comment: Please remove your second, unrelated question and make it a new question.  Once you do that, I think both of your questions will receive upvotes.

Comment: done....... thx

Comment: nominatim has become an increasingly comprehensive solution.  i need brazilian locations and, until last year, it was close to useless.  but now, i get the data i need without depending on paid services.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want the hassle of managing the entire OSM dataset required for worldwide address datasets you'll need an online service.

As well as Nominatim, Cloudmade have a [geocoding API](http://developers.cloudmade.com/projects/show/geocoding-http-api) to work with OSM data. There are reverse geocoding examples [here](http://developers.cloudmade.com/wiki/geocoding-http-api/Examples#Reverse-geocoding). It includes a **distance** parameter to allow radius searches. E.g.

http://geocoding.cloudmade.com/8ee2a50541944fb9bcedded5165f09d9/geocoding/v2/find.js?object_type=cafe&around=51.51558,-0.141449&results=5&distance=500

If you aren't tied to OSM then have a look at the Google [Reverse Geocoding service](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/services.html#ReverseGeocoding) and [example](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/examples/geocoding-reverse.html). The docs state it searches within a "tolerance" but then neglects to say what this tolerance is.