# What is the best way to do reverse geocoding with PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, reverse-geocoding

Is there a way to do reverse geocoding with PostGIS? There's a lot of information on the Web but I found it very confusing...

I have imported osm data into my own Postgres with PostGIS database. Now I want to make geocoding and reverse geocoding with my database. I don't know if there are some Stored Procedures, or a project somewhere that takes care of my issue.

The next step that I want to do is make a webservice that can handle this kind of requests, but that is another question.

Comment: [There are a few results](http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=reverse%20geocoding) when you search on this site for reverse geocoding. One answer that stands out is [this one](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4816/reverse-geocoding-libraries/5400#5400) about services that provide it.

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. Is there a particular problem you're having? Or do you need help with the general approach to reverse geocoding?

Comment: I've already tried using Nominatim, but I had issues using "gazetteer" output. It throws a "Segmentation fault" each time I import the osm data.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Finally, I understand the way to do geocode and reverse geocode with my PostGIS database. I made a stored procedure that finds geometry types that are near a point. This stored procedure uses the distance function to get the nearest points. After that, I've created a RESTful API that calls this stored procedure to resolve the reverse geocoding requests.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I've understood that Nominatim project creates an API for databases that have been imported from  OSM. So you don't have to create any stored procedure for reverse geocoding and geocoding. Also you don't have to make any webservice to resolve the requests through the web.

Hope this helps someone.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION reverse_geocode (lat double precision, lon double precision)
RETURNS text AS 
$BODY$ 
declare  point geometry;  rec record;  geocode text; 
begin  
    point := geomfromtext('POINT('||lat||' '||lon||')', 4326);  
    select name, distance(way, point) as dist  
    into rec  from mapserverdb_point  
    order by dist asc limit 1;  
    geocode := rec.name;  
    return geocode; 
end; 
$BODY$   
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Can we see the procedure?

Comment: Of course: 
`CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION reverse_geocode(lat double precision, lon double precision)
  RETURNS text AS
$BODY$
declare
 point geometry;
 rec record;
 geocode text;
begin
 point := geomfromtext('POINT('||lat||' '||lon||')', 4326);
 select name, distance(way, point) as dist
 into rec
 from mapserverdb_point
 order by dist asc limit 1;
 geocode := rec.name;
 return geocode;
end;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
`

Answer (score 4):

PostGIS 2.0 tiger geocoder has a reverse geocoder utilizing Tiger data.  The geocoder will install fine on PostGIS 1.5 8.4+ or higher.

If you are in US, might be the easiest to use since it's all packaged as plpgsql functions.

http://www.postgis.org/documentation/manual-svn/Extras.html#Tiger_Geocoder
http://www.postgis.org/documentation/manual-svn/Reverse_Geocode.html

Comment: Thanks. I didn't need US information for reverse geocode. Now I have understand the way reverse geocode works with PostGIS databases.

Thanks a lot.